# Can I install Ubuntu apt-get packages offline?

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, apt-get

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my system. I don't have any Internet connection to the system.

How can I install various packages? Is there a package collection available as CD/DVD (which I can download)?

Comment: Use askubuntu.com for these questions

Comment: This question doesn't really belong to stackoverflow. Maybe, superuser? Or askubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike debian, which has a set of disks that covers everything, for an offline install on ubuntu, you'll probably need to snarf the packages you need off the repositories for your version from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Remember to grab the prerequisites too, and install the prerequisites first, then the software using dpkg

If you don't mind a little more setup, but want something less annoying to do, and graphical-  try using [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) - You install keryx on the system you want to update (so it can make a list of packages), and you can run an agent on another windows or linux box to download the packages you want to install and update to a USB key for install to the offline system

Comment: keryx will not support Ubuntu 11.04 now.

Answer (score 0):

This (archived form of a now-defunct website) may help you using apt-get install with the -o option

https://web.archive.org/web/20130301085200/http://www.sinarpelangi.com/how-to-install-deb-package-offline-using-apt-get/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yep, the link is now broken, rendering this answer unhelpful. I'll see if I can find an archive.org version anyway

Comment: Even with the archived link, a proper answer on Super User should at least summarize the solution so that people don't have to click through to another site. Some users who come here cannot visit site-external links even if they wanted to.